# passing variable in r system command

Tags: r, shell, system

I am trying to pass variable as an argument to system command in R.

```
> system("ls>abc.csv")  #this works
> k<-"abc.csv"          
> system("ls>k")        #this does not work
> system2("ls>k")       #this does not work
sh: ls>k: command not found
> system("ls>$k")      #this does not work
sh: $k: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: You need to actually construct the string as you want it to read.  Look into sprintf, paste, or any other string manipulation/concatenation function.

Comment: You can paste in the variable value to the string `system(paste0("ls>", k)) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` to build the OS command and pass to `system`

```
system(paste("ls >", k))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that R does not recognize variable k if you put it in a string.
But indeed it is very useful to put the file name in a variable if you want to use it again and again.

Can you try

```
system(paste0("ls>", k))
```

If this works, you can also write a small function:

```
"%&%" <- function(a, b)paste0(a, b)
```

And then you can do

```
system("ls>"%&%k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first define a string with the message you want, for instance mystr=paste("ls", "/data/files/"), then call system as system(mystr), and it will work. Actually it is almost the same answer as above with more emphasis on the creating message as a string first